# Is it possible to cutomize the admin view in twilio flex-ui?

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex, twilioflexwebchat

I currently can't find a clear way of customising the admin view for twilio flex? I basically would like to remove the test drive chat and the only way I found to do it is to hide it by changing the style.display to none via JavaScript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Admin view is actually a plugin itself, and it is not customisable.

If you have feature requests for the admin view, such as being able to configure whether the chat appears, I recommend you talk to your account executive.